# Validations using Mongoose models

Tags: mongodb, validation, mongoose

I have a question regarding validations in Mongoose models. I don't find them that useful.

When I am creating a new model, my code is

```
const model = new Comment(commentJson);
const error = model.validateSync();
assert.ok(error, error.errors);
```

With creating new data, validation is somewhat useful. But consider the code with updating an existing model.

```
Comment.findByIdAndUpdate(id, commentJson);
```

With the above code, I don't have a chance at model validation. I could retrieve the current model, update it with commentJson and then do a validate on the model. But the code looks a bit ugly.

Instead, I feel more tempted to write my own assert statements rather than rely on mongoose validation. Is there any way to do validations with mongoose without hitting the database twice for updates? Thanks.

Comment: may be pre update hooks will help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use this:

```
try {
  let updatedComment = await Comment.findByIdAndUpdate(
    id, 
    commentJson, 
    {
      new: true,
      runValidators: true
    }
  );

  // Deal with result.
  console.log(updatedComment);
} catch (err) {
  // Deal with error.
  console.log(err);
}
```

When Mongoose updates the document it will run validation against the model's schema. If the validation fails the catch block will handle it.

Or with callbacks if you want:

```
Comment.findByIdAndUpdate(
  id, 
  commentJson, 
  {
    new: true,
    runValidators: true
  }, (err, updatedComment) => {
    if (err) throw err;

    console.log(updatedComment);
  }
);
```

Mongoose generally runs the validators automatically when calling `save()` and `create()`. I don't think I've seen that many people run the validator manually before. For the update functions the validators are turned off by default. Setting `runValidators: true` will turn them on. See [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html) and [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findByIdAndUpdate).

Comment: Thanks. That is really neat.